# UITableview scrollsToTop pressing UINavigationbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uinavigationbar, pressed

I have a `UIView` with a `UINavigationBar`, a `UITabBar` and a `UITableView`.
When i press the status bar the `UITableView` scrolls to top because i have it set to `TRUE`.

I want to be able to do the same, by pressing the `UINavigationBar` like it happens in some apps. Setting the `UITableView` to `scrollsToTop = TRUE` only works if the user presses the `StatusBar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

How about adding a `TapGestureRecogniser` on your `UINavigationBar`? This will only work if you dont have any buttons on your navigationBar.

```
//Create a tap gesture with the method to call when tap gesture has been detected
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navBarClicked):];

//isolate tap to only the navigation bar
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

//same method name used when setting the tapGesure's selector
-(void)navBarClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    //add code to scroll your tableView to the top.
}
```

and that's about it really.

Some people have found that their back button stops working when adding a tap gesture to the navigation bar, so you can do one of two things:

1. Method 2: Set the user interaction enabled to yes and set the tap gesture recogniser like shown in method 2 in detail.
2. Method 3: Use a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method called `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch` and make it return `NO` when the touch's view is a button, otherwise return `YES`. See method 3 in detail.

**Method 2 from point 1: - feels dirty/hackish**

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

**Method 3 from point 2: - a lot better, the right way**

implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in your `.h` file, and in your `.m` file add the following:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures when a navigation Item is tapped
    if ((touch.view == backbutton)) {//your back button/left button/whatever buttons you have
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```